# java and postgresql: duplicate key value violation, despite sending none duplicate keys

Tags: java, postgresql, constraints, primary-key, sql-insert

From what I deduce, it seems that I attempt to insert into my postgresql database a new row, with a new primary key combination. And yet it complains that I insert the same keys several times.

The evidence (from error-log):

```
ERROR com.saxo.read.postgres.RequestLoggingStore - Unable to insert request correctly, uri: /someUrlHere, uuid: a7813f97-7c0d-4739-b20b-a2a6ab2f32a3, at: 1470137399294243
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "requestlogging_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id, "timestamp")=(a7813f97-7c0d-4739-b20b-a2a6ab2f32a3, 1470137399294243) already exists.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
        ....
ERROR com.saxo.read.postgres.RequestLoggingStore - Unable to insert request correctly, uri: /someUrlHere, uuid: 1891dc28-64b8-4a16-8d22-67af6a605aa0, at: 1470137399293662
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "requestlogging_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id, "timestamp")=(a7813f97-7c0d-4739-b20b-a2a6ab2f32a3, 1470137399294243) already exists.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
        ....
```

As you can see, PQSL complains that I have a duplicate key violation, at it SHOULD think, if I had given it the values that it complains about. 
`(a7813f97-7c0d-4739-b20b-a2a6ab2f32a3, 1470137399294243)` is a duplicate key. HOWEVER, as can be seen from my error log in RequestLoggingStore , the uuid and timestamp reported are not the same as those reported by PSQL, and is NOT a duplicate key.

I immediately assumed that I have made a mistake in the code, and that the reported UUID and timestamp is not what I insert into the postgresql database. But I don't see how this is possible from the code below:

```
public String put(String uri, String method, String body, String headers, String userId) {
        String uuid = null;
        long timestamp = stamper.timestamp();
        try {
            uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            insertQuery.setString(1, uri);
            insertQuery.setString(2, body);
            insertQuery.setString(3, method);
            insertQuery.setString(4, headers);
            insertQuery.setString(5, userId);
            insertQuery.setLong(6, timestamp);
            insertQuery.setString(7, uuid);

            insertQuery.execute();
            return uuid;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unable to insert request correctly, uri: {}, uuid: {}, at: {}", uri, uuid, timestamp, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Just in case you want to see the insert query also:

```
insertQuery = postgresConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "+TableName+"( "+listOfArgs+" ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? );");
```

UUID should either be null, or the same value as reported by my error logger, correct?

How could there be a difference between the 2?

Did I make a mistake or is there something wrong with java driver for psql?

I am logging all incoming requests to my web service/API. When testing it seems to work fine. Does it become too stressed under high loads?

Comment: show table schema too

Comment: Could you by any chance have some triggers that on insert do another insert?

Comment: Very hard to answer without an SSCCE. I've used JDBC connector for PostgreSQL for several years and never found any problem of this magnitude. Are you using multi-threading or transactions?

Comment: As a side note, don't return from inside a `try` or `catch` block.

Comment: Btw where is `insertQuery` defined? Where is it closed?

Comment: The first error message seems to be complaining about the correct key: `ERROR com.saxo.read.postgres.RequestLoggingStore - Unable to insert request correctly, uri: /someUrlHere, uuid: a7813f97-7c0d-4739-b20b-a2a6ab2f32a3, at: 1470137399294243` and `Detail: Key (id, "timestamp")=(a7813f97-7c0d-4739-b20b-a2a6ab2f32a3, 1470137399294243) already exists.`

Comment: I am inclined to believe Postgres more then you and that you are indeed sending the same value twice (for whatever reasons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `insertQuery` is a class field, the method `put` could be called in two threads and overwrite the same unique SQL field. Hence on execute the "same" record (insertQuery) is attempted.

The best is to keep all in local variables, and do a try-with-resources.

(Also one may leave the key generation to the database, and query `PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()`.)

Comment: This seems very plausible. As I do indeed have several threads running, all accepting incoming requests.

If I understand correctly, the solution would be to replace my try { with
    try (PreparedStatement insertQuery = postgresConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "+TableName+"( "+listOfArgs+" ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? );"); ){

Comment: Yes, that seems to give a reentrant put method

Comment: By the way PreparedStatement.executeUpdate would be better, and clearParameters might in other cases come in handy. _For all readers coming here._

Comment: Making a new prepared statement for each put method did indeed *SOLVE* the problem.
Jopp, you are welcome to expand on your comment above. Should I use update instead of Insert?

Comment: I just meant that I saw an `PreparedStatement.execute()` (?) where a `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()` is more appropriate - that also is for INSERT/DELETE and such SQL statements.